# Putting replicated IB UIViews in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I want to use a UIScrollView, which inside it has several blocks, which have been designed in IB as a UIView. The UIView in replicated in the scroll view. The elements in these blocks can be changed in the code. For instance, the numbers below would be UILabels. What's the best way of making this?

```
----------------------------
|                  |       |
|   1.             |   2.  |
|                  |       |  > scrolls this way
|                  |       |
|                  |       |
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make the scroll view the right size (i.e. width of your custom view times number of views you want to show).
2. Programmatically add instances of your custom view at the right offset as `subviews`.
3. Use the `tag` property in order to help you to identify your views. (You can conveniently access them with `[scrollView viewWithTag:x]`.)
4. The labels would be again `subviews` of your custom views.
5. If desired, set the scroll view's `contentOffset` to the correct point to show the desired view.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the examples for using a UITableView with a custom-designed cell. If I understand what you want to do, it's essentially the same but using a generic UIScrollView instead of a table view. In summary, the examples show you how to load a nib that assigns the view to a temporary property on your view controller. Then you add the view where you want in your hierarchy. If you load the nib file again, it will make a new view object, so you can make as many copies of your IB-designed view as you want, and change the properties for each one separately to show different data.